# Can the jupyter lab be used as a markdown editor?

Tags: markdown, jupyter

I am writing an article for a web page (with references, images, tables and footnotes). I have to use Markdown. As I am just learning it I thought of the jupyter notebook which allows to write in markdown and then export to HTML and .md and others.

Has anyone used the jupyter notebook to write web articles? Or can you give me suggestions?

Comment: I use visual studio code, along with a markdown plugin (of which there are lots)

Comment: Yes, JupyterLab can be used as a markdown editor and does not requite any plugins.  There is a [built-in markdown preview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQsRlqK-z1c) to make the process easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you use https://ultraedit.com because It simplifies markdown, and yes...  Jupyter can run markdown...

### Better suggested Markdown Editors

Many other online editors and programming websites such as glitch.com or replit.com both support markdown in `.md` files.

but many others are listed here. Below.

#### MacDown

https://macdown.uranusjr.com/

MacDown is a robust tool that offers syntax highlighting, live preview, and a minimalistic appearance that makes it easy to apply Markdown formatting.

> The editor’s author, Tzu-Ping Chun, released MacDown after announcing that one of his favorite MarkDown editors, Mou, was shutting down its development. Chun started from the ground up, dedicating weekends to put together his own solution, and MacDown was the result.

> Despite its simple design, MacDown is fully featured with highly customizable > language rendering, auto-completion, and lots of Markdown syntax. Plus, > exporting to HTML or PDF delivers consistently good results.

#### ghostwriter

https://wereturtle.github.io/ghostwriter/

> ghostwriter gives you a distraction-free environment for writing captivating content, including a clean interface and a full-screen option.

> You can preview your work in HTML, use the “Focus Mode” to narrow your attention to a single paragraph, and even create your own custom style sheet to preview how your content will appear on the internet.

> The tool also has a built-in processor that enables you to export documents to HTML. Alternatively, you can export to Word, PDF, ODT, and other formats by installing a document converter like Pandoc
> ghostwriter has built-in dark and light themes that deliver an aesthetic user experience out of the gate. And if that wasn’t enough, it lets you build your own! With support for background visuals, you can create the environment you prefer for your writing.

**These supported editors all are free, thank you.**